# Getting users data in week, month & year format from healthkit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I need a little help with the implementation of HealthKit in my app. I am working with Swift 4 Xcode 9. I am using the following code to get the users step count for particular day:

```
func getTodaysSteps(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
        let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!

        let now = Date()
        let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)

        let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { (_, result, error) in
            var resultCount = 0.0

            guard let result = result else {
       //         log.error("Failed to fetch steps = \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "N/A")")
                completion(resultCount)
                return
            }

            if let sum = result.sumQuantity() {
                resultCount = sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(resultCount)
            }
        }

        healthStore.execute(query)
    }
```

Now I want to get the users step count and calories for each day of an entire month. In other words I want to get users past step count in the week, month and year format. Can anyone please help me with the same ?

Answer (score 1):

your just need to set from date (in your case it could be aWeekAgo, aMothAgo, aYearAgo) and toDate is Current Date

```
let sevneDaysAgo = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())

    let currentDate = Date.init()

    PedometerManager.shared.getPedometerDataFromDate(fromDate: sevneDaysAgo, toDate: currentDate) { [weak self] (data, error, errorMsg)  in            
            if(error == nil && data != nil) {

            if let count =  data?.numberOfSteps {

            }

            if let distance = data?.distance {

                let roundDis = round(distance.doubleValue)
                let dis = String.init(format: "%.3f",roundDis)
            }


            if let pace = data?.currentPace {

            }

            if let cadence  = data?.currentCadence {

            }

            if let ascend = data!.floorsAscended {

            }

            if let desc = data!.floorsDescended {

            }

            if let activity = self?.activityName {

            }


        }
    }
```

you have to use CMPedometer class

Comment: Yes i tried that but that gives me a sum of all the steps for one week. I want the individual data for each day of the entire week. Something like an array or something.

Comment: for this you have to track data of each date at your end.
otherwise you have to call method multiple times or in loop by changing date of individual day ,